# WCF RIA Services - returning custom class of two already defined classes

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight / WCF RIA Services application that uses EF 4.  Currently, there is a domain service that returns two types of classes, OrderItem and Event.  I'd like to create a class that contains both of these items for easier manipulation of the data at the XAML level.  Here is what the class that combines the two classes looks like:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public partial class EventOrderItem  {
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public string EventOrderItemKey { get { return Event.EventID.ToString() + "-" + OrderItem.OrderItemID.ToString(); } }

    [DataMember]
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public OrderItem OrderItem { get; set; }
}
```

The domain service returns the EventOrderItem, but the Event and OrderItem properties are not present on the class.  How do I get RIA Services to pick up on these two properties?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible because wouldn't this make the class a complex type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, unfortunately it's not possible (it's one of my biggest bugbears with RIA Services).  According to the RIA Services UserVoice site (http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services) they're working on enabling complex types now, but for the time being you're out of luck :(.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working in a similar scenario in my application by making use of the [[Include]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.includeattribute%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) and [[Association]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associationattribute%28VS.95%29.aspx) attributes on the included types.  I'm using POCO objects instead of EF4, though, so your mileage may vary.